# Does Frost Walker work with boats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Two questions:

Can boats go extremely fast on frosted ice like on normal ice?

Do you go too fast on a boat for the Frost Walker to create the ice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Minecraft 1.9.2 prepatches regarding the boats going fast on ice-bug, does the boat move quick both on normal and frosted ice, but the ice won't spawn if you're sitting in a boat. The ice only spawn when you're wearing the boots directly over the watersource-block itself, sadly.

If you want a more detailed descripiton, watch the lovely mr. Ethoslab explain [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9_QUPYX4mM)!